# DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener variable cannot be resolved [java]

Tags: java, android, dialog, onclicklistener

I am building an alert dialog with a selection list. I can not figure out why my variable for the OnClickListener cannot resolve.

I have put the code in a separate activity by itself and it works but inside my main activity it does not.

```
    public void categoryDialogShow(final Context context, String[] categoryOptions){
        final AlertDialog actions;

        AlertDialog.Builder categoryAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        categoryAlert.setTitle("Choose a Category");

        categoryAlert.setItems(categoryOptions, actionListener);
//=============================================================
//==============actionListener cannot be resolved to a variable
//=============================================================
        categoryAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        actions = categoryAlert.create();

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener actionListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          //goto category list with which as the category
        }
      };
      actions.show();
}
```

This is the activity that works with no problems:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    AlertDialog actions;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Activity");
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Click for Options");
        button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose an Option");
        String[] options = { "A", "B", "C" };
        builder.setItems(options, actionListener);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        actions = builder.create();

        setContentView(button);
      }
      DialogInterface.OnClickListener actionListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          switch (which) {
          case 0: // Delete
            break;
          case 1: // Copy
            break;
          case 2: // Edit
            break;
          default:
            break;
          }
        }
      };
      View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          actions.show();
        }
      };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the declaration above where you need to reference it:

```
public void categoryDialogShow(final Context context, String[] categoryOptions){
    final AlertDialog actions;
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener actionListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          //goto category list with which as the category
        }
      };

    AlertDialog.Builder categoryAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    categoryAlert.setTitle("Choose a Category");

    categoryAlert.setItems(categoryOptions, actionListener);
    categoryAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    actions = categoryAlert.create();


  actions.show();
}
```

The reason it works in the other class, is that the `actionListener` reference is a class member variable, just as I suspected.
Notice that the declaration is not inside any method.  You could do the same with your new Activity:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener actionListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          //goto category list with which as the category
        }
      };

public void categoryDialogShow(final Context context, String[] categoryOptions){
    final AlertDialog actions;

    AlertDialog.Builder categoryAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    categoryAlert.setTitle("Choose a Category");

    categoryAlert.setItems(categoryOptions, actionListener);
    categoryAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    actions = categoryAlert.create();


  actions.show();
}
```

Comment: yep, moving the declaration worked. I edited my question with the tutorial script I was using. Can you see why it would work there?

Comment: @silversunhunter just updated the answer, my original guess was correct.

Comment: Is this a scope issue? In the example, The dialogInterface is outside of the oncreate(), whereas in my script the dialogInterface is within the method.

Comment: @silversunhunter Yes, absolutely.  If it's a class member variable, it has Class level scope, and it can be safely de-referenced in any method (as long as you've initialized it correctly).  In your code where it wasn't working, it had method scope, and you were trying to reference it before it was declared.

Comment: Ok. TIL... Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Either declare

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener actionListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          //goto category list with which as the category
        }
      };
```

before

```
 categoryAlert.setItems(categoryOptions, actionListener);
```

or declare it outside your method.

Comment: Thank you for the response. You are right, moving the declaration worked!